# Two classes have the same XML type name for AXIS

Tags: wsdl, axis

Facing the following exception while trying to deploy my app to AS:

```
Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://WS.gid.com/}fetchLogsResponse". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
            at com.gid.WS.FetchLogs_Response
            at public com.gid.WS.FetchLogs_Response com.gid.WS.jaxws.FetchLogsResponse._return
            at com.gid.WS.jaxws.FetchLogsResponse
    this problem is related to the following location:
            at com.gid.WS.jaxws.FetchLogsResponse
```

I've googled a bit, and found that it's necessary to annotate my classes correctly, but i am using axis generated web service, so i am unable to annotate classes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found: web service has been deployed twice - through a wsdd and via @Service annotation by jaxws. So, i just forgot to remove @Service annotation while migrating to axis.